# FSEEK offset accepts more than what it should accept

Tags: c, fseek

Following the [Specification:](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2)

> For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET.

I understand that `offset` must be the retun value of a `ftell` function, or 0, and `whence` must be `SEET_SET` (or 0). But I used some integers as offsets and different `SEEK_...` and it seemed to work well.

For example, these worked:

```
fseek(file, 4, SEEK_CUR);
fseek(file, -1, SEEK_END);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

When I read the specification it seems to me that it should not work. I tried to use fseek this way many times, and it never failed. Why does it work, what point am I not getting?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Is the file open for reading and/or writing?

Comment: `ftell` returns current position which you **might** want to use as offset and that current position returned is `long int`. So you can use any long integer as offset

Comment: Chris Turner it's open in mode r+.

Comment: Badda what code should I show? My question is about the fseek function and how it works in general

Comment: You are not validating the return value of `fseek`. If it returns nonzero, there was something wrong. ("The fseek function returns nonzero only for a request that cannot be satisfied.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I read the specification it seems to me that it should not work.

The specification, states what must work. It should be seen as the minimum requirements for someone creating a c library (i.e. the implementor of `fseek` et al).

Incorrect use might still work, but there is no guarantee. The result would depend on the platform.

For instance, the Linux manual page for `fseek`says:

> The fseek() function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. The new position, measured in bytes, is obtained by adding offset bytes to the position specified by whence. If whence is set to SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END, the offset is relative to the start of the file, the current position indicator, or end-of-file, respectively. A successful call to the fseek() function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream and undoes any effects of the ungetc(3) function on the same stream.

A you can see, the things you tried will work in Linux for both text and binary streams. However, there may exist platforms where `fseek` won't work with SEEK_CUR or SEEK_END for text streams.

Note also that a stream could be associated with different things: a file, a keyboard, a socket, a terminal window, a device, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the ftell documentation you can read

> For text streams, the numerical value may not be meaningful but can
>   still be used to restore the position to the same position later using
>   fseek (if there are characters put back using ungetc still pending of
>   being read, the behavior is undefined).

What you cited means that it may have sense to use it if you know where you want to place your pointer at, and you may know it because in precedence you invoked ftell().

All your calls to fseek are valid, but in a text file it has not much sense to move using fseek because it is not a random-access (binary) file, but still this does not mean that it is wrong to use it.

For a text file, you can find [here](https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-file-io-using-text-files) the most common functions to access it, like fscanf(), fprintf() and so on.

Comment: What would be more appropriate than fseek in a text file?

Comment: Considering that you know the structure in a text file, you should use these functions:
[LINK](https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-file-io-using-text-files)
Anyway, I added it to the answer.

Comment: well, is there one of these functions that enables to go backwards, like would do a `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR)`? it seems to me that these functions only read next characters/lines. And I still don't get why it is not most appropriate to use `fseek`

Comment: If you save in a text file "hello" and on a new line "world", how would you access to the 'o' using fseek? If you saved it in windows, it will be stored as "hello\r\nworld", if in linux it would just have "hello\nworld". This means that if you open the file as text, you are asking to decode it and interpret, and a random access using fseek() may be difficult to handle, it has more sense to use fscanf() to read a line into a string and than compute it in the code to access what you need.

Comment: I suggest you read [here](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2011/08/binary-vs-text-file-in-c.html) for more details on the differences.

Comment: On unix, variable-width encodings like UTF-8 create the same problem that the accursed `\r\n` does on Windows. Byte offsets are different from character counts. If a byte offset is what you want, just avoid opening in text mode and you got it! If a character count is what you want, you basically have to give up on seeking and just read all the characters between where you are and where you're going.

Comment: Actually for the program that I'm doing right now I think that fseek is totally appropriate, even though my program works with a text file open in r+. but i get the point of prefering other functions to seek characters

Answer (score 0):

All your `fseek` calls are valid. The number you provide as the second argument is an *offset*, meaning it is relative to the seek type that your provide as the third parameter.

```
fseek(file, 4, SEEK_CUR);    // seek 4 bytes forward from current position
fseek(file, -1, SEEK_END);   // seek to 1 byte before the end of the file
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);    // does nothing.
```

But see also user Tu.ma's explanation that the seek positions are not accurate and/or can be meaningless if the file has been opened in text mode (especially under Windows because of carriage return/line feed translation).

Comment: Strictly speaking they are not valid according to the C specification. This, I presume is because, for a text stream, the logical position in the file is not necessarily the same as the number of bytes from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you using fseek to go beyond the current size of the file. Because doing so allows you to write data at that point, filling the as yet unwritten gap with NULs. Like with this example code - it creates a file with 1000 NULs and then `"hello\n"`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen("test","w"); 
    if(f)
        {
        fseek(f,1000,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(f,"hello\n");
        fclose(f);
        }
    else
        {
        perror("fopen");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason why the definition of `fseek` is as it is in the C standard is that your logical position in a text file may not correlate to the physical number of bytes from the start of the text file.

For example, in Windows implementations, it is not uncommon to convert`\r\n` in the file on disk to just `\n` to maintain compatibility with Unix line endings. So if your file looks like this:

```
hello\r\nworld
```

i.e. two lines, and you `fseek` to position 6, would you expect to be on the `\n` or the `w`? If you tried to find out by using `fgetc` on Windows to count the characters, you'd assume you would be on the `w`. But `fseek` might chance advance to byte 6 without scanning for line endings.

**Edit**

> And if we use the fgetc function, each character that we read increases our position of 1: the file cursor goes to the next character after the previous one was read. Is that a problem?

Yes. The problem is in the definition of "character". If you are in an environment that uses DOS conventions, using `fgetc` on a text stream when the next two bytes are `0x0d 0x0a` advances the file position by two but only returns the `0x0a`. There may be other conversions that the implementation chooses to make, like turning decomposed Unicode into precomposed unicode or vice versa.

The wording in the C standard allows implementations to lose the one to one mapping between bytes in the file and characters returned by `fgetc` without having to overcomplicate `fseek`.

Comment: As I understand it, the newline is a character, and the sixth (counting from 0) position corresponds to \n. And if we use the `fgetc` function, each character that we read increases our position of 1: the file cursor goes to the next character after the previous one was read. Is that a problem? I understood that the compiler or some library automatically transforms /n into /r/n when needed.

Comment: Line endings in DOS/Windows historically consist of two `char`s a `0x0d` and a `0x0a`. Windows C libraries silently dropped the `0x0d` in text streams to make them look like Unix text streams.